# Regular Expression to get the last value in the url

Tags: regex, apache

I need to get the last value from the URL

Following URL scenario:

`http://www.abc.com/aa/bb/cc`

`http://www.abc.com/aa/bb/cc?ab=1`

`http://www.abc.com/aa/bb/cc/`

`http://www.abc.com/aa/bb/cc/?ab=1`

From the above URL listing i need to take out the cc from the URL
Regex Expression to get value cc

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you need to do this just with a regex? You'd be better off using a URL parser to extract the path component and then pull the `cc` out of that.

Comment: @muistooshort i cannot use any URL parser as i want to use the regex expression in apache. so i would be needing only the regex expression to do that.

Comment: @AlexW I need to get the last value in the URL as in the above case its cc. The regex must validate all the URL mention above and can get the value from URL. I would be requiring this value in apache.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
([^/?]+)(?=/?(?:$|\?))
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?322bq

---

#### Explanation:

- **`([^/?]+)`** - Matches any characters that are *not* a slash or a question mark.
- **`(?=`** - Starts a look-ahead.
- **`/?`** - Optionally matches a slash.
- **`(?:$|\?)`** - Either matches a question mark, or asserts that we're at the end.
- **`)`** - Closes the look-ahead.

---

**Note:** In the demo, it's also matching after the `?` character, since it's doing a global search. That shouldn't concern you though.

Comment: The thing is i only need the value cc and don't want to match after ? character. SO how can i only match to get the value cc

Comment: @Prateek - You will only get the `cc` part. The demo uses the **global** flag, so it also matches after that. You should be OK though. See here: http://regexr.com?322bt

Comment: the value i am getting cc is correct but i don't want to do a global search because it is creating a problem in Apache. Am not getting the full value in apache